# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

...акцент следует делать или на глаза**, или** на губы

Answer (score 1):

Всё верно, нужна: однородные члены с повторяющимся союзом.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, поскольку однородные члены соединены  повторяюшимся союзом или